# Working With KCL 2.x is causing issue while "Syncing Kinesis shard info"

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, amazon-dynamodb-streams, amazon-kcl

I am using AWS SDK V2 with KCL 2.x.
I have enabled dynamodb table with streams.
While creating the KCL Scheduler I am using the below configuration

```
TableDescription tableDescription =
                dynamoDbAsyncClient.describeTable(DescribeTableRequest.builder()
                        .tableName("table1").build()).get().table();

var streamArn = tableDescription.latestStreamArn()
var subscriberId = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName() + ":" + UUID.randomUUID();

ConfigsBuilder configsBuilder = new ConfigsBuilder(streamArn, <applicationName>,    kinesisAsyncClient, dynamoDbAsyncClient, cloudWatchAsyncClient, subscriberId, shardRecordProcessorFactory).tableName("table1Stream");

new Scheduler(
                configsBuilder.checkpointConfig(),
                configsBuilder.coordinatorConfig(),
                configsBuilder.leaseManagementConfig(),
                configsBuilder.lifecycleConfig(),
                configsBuilder.metricsConfig(),
                configsBuilder.processorConfig(),
                configsBuilder.retrievalConfig());
```

I am getting the error :-

```
Value 'arn_aws_dynamodb_<>_table/<tableName>/stream/2021-08-11T12:30:47.041' at 'streamName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+ (Service: Kinesis, Status Code: 400, Request ID: ff044658-ead5-4d7a-a259-4833e8071fc4, Extended Request ID:
```

Please provide suggestions on how to fix it.

I have tried by updating the value to

```
'arn_aws_dynamodb_<>_table/<tableName>/stream/2021-08-11T12_30_47.041'
```

but still getting the same error.